# What are some FOSS libraries for reading epub, mobi, pdf, or other eBook formats for Android or Java?

Tags: java, android

What are some FOSS libraries for reading epub, mobi, pdf, or other eBook formats for Android or Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [**epublib**](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android) for android. It is released under the [**GNU Lesser General Public License**](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/license).

It also has some **quick start examples**:

```
EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
Book book = epubReader.readEpub(new FileInputStream("mybook.epub"));

// set title
book.getMetadata().setTitles(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("an awesome book");}});

// write epub
EpubWriter epubWriter = new EpubWriter();
epubWriter.write(book, new FileOutputStream("mynewbook.epub"));
```